# How to create a WebSite on Sdl Tridion using core service.please write the step.

Tags: core-service

I want to create a website using core service on Sdl Tridion .please write the steps of creating a web site using this.

Comment: I think you should first get a training on the SDL Tridion as your question does not make any sense.

I would say you should elaborate your question and add what all you have done. I am afraid open ended quesions might not get an answer

Comment: Just noticed, there are 19 questions but you haven't accepted any answer yet. Please start accepting the answers on all questions which helped you to solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDL Tridion is a content management system used to manage the Content of you website and the pages along with the presentation (the way content is being displayed on the page) with many other things.

Core Service is a WCF based Interface provided by SDL Tridion to interact with the data/content stored with in the Tridion.

**UPDATE:**

See the requested flow to create a webpage in SDL Tridion as below:

The **Custom Code** bock in the diagram below is where actually your Core Service will come into the picture.

[image]

Comment: I create a schema then attach the schema on component then i create a component building block then i create a component template and page template and page template building block.this is right way of creating a web site on SDL Tridion. please give the answer because i am new on sdl tridion

Comment: See the update to the answer and refer the image attached there to understand the whole process. Also, can you edit your question and what you have put in the comment, can you move it to the question so it makes more sense and other professional can also reply.

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to Tridion then I *must* insist that you read the great "[Getting Started](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-E19B53AE-84C2-488C-8939-853EC1DC7EAD)" guides that we have in our documentation, in particular the ones titled *Quick Guide to Creating a Page Template* and *Quick Guide to Creating a Component Template*.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't (and probably can't) create a website using the Core Service. You probably want to use the OData Service as that is a Content Delivery technology rather than a Content Management technology. It is very rare that you web tier will ever have access to the Core Service.

As others have said, please consider getting some training or consulting support before starting to create such an implementation.